# Recommended type of exception to throw when a retval resulting from a stored procedure call is non-zero

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedures, ado

I have a number of Stored Procedures being called with the use of ADO.NET and most of them are returning a RETVAL.
At the moment in case if RETVAL is not zero, a new FaultException() is thrown, but I am not sure if this the best approach. Maybe it is, but possibly SqlException would be better, only if it has a public ctor available. But it does not, meaning that maybe SqlException is also not the proper idea.

What would be the recommended exception to be thrown if called Stored Procedure returns a non-zero value (meaning it fails)?

Currently our legacy project handles it like on the example below (NOTE: CreateFaultException does more or less what 'smelly code' does):

```
public Employee GetEmployee(int id)
    {
        string reason = nameof(GetEmployee);

        try
        {
            DataTable dataTable;
            long retVal = ExecuteCommand("ps_getemployee", CommandType.StoredProcedure, out dataTable,
                true,
                CreateSqlParameter(parameterName: "id", value: id));

            if (retVal != 0)
            {
                // smelly code here: 3 new objects created:
                throw new FaultException<FaultExceptionSvc>(new FaultExceptionSvc(null, reason, message: retVal.ToString(), faultNbr: errorCode, skipFrames: 2), new FaultReason(reason));
                // I want to replace it by more proper exception if any.
            }

            CreateEmployeeFromRow(dataTable.Rows[0]));
        }
        catch (FaultException<FaultExceptionSvc>)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw CreateFaultException(ex, reason);
        }
    }
```

Excerpt of SP generating a return value:

```
if @@error = 0
begin
    select @retval = 0
end
else
begin
    select @retval = -1
end
```

Thanks, Radek

Comment: If you know the meaning of that return values then throw something appropriate for that specific problem? A infrastructure problem surfaced here is presumably something completely different then just a missing Employee and should be handled differently. Maybe the last isn't even an Exceptional case. So there is no proper recommendation for any kind of failure or for any current architecture you might already have and this should fit in.

Comment: Instead of mucking around with return values, either let an exception get thrown from SQL, or use `THROW 50001, 'Some error message here', 1;` from the SQL. Then just catch `SqlException`

Comment: [The .NET exception model is a Pokémon based system.](https://twitter.com/jaredpar/status/1355257692005142529)

Comment: Just to let you know, I cannot change the exiting SPs code, so I need to deal with the retval on the .net caller side, so to say.

Comment: I am confused: The function is non-void but lacks `return`? And you may want to refactor the inner throw out of the try/catch, so you don't have to rethrow.

Comment: Should you even be dealing with exceptions here? is getting a return value other than zero is an indication of an exceptional situation, or perhaps just that the employ was not found? (in this case, you should probably just return null or something like that and have your business layer decide what to do)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to catch and deal with [SqlException Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).